# Query error #1241

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, syntax-error

```
SELECT id from reparacoes WHERE id_reparacao 
IN (select DISTINCT re.id_reparacao 
FROM reparacoes re 
WHERE(edit_user="loja cascais" AND estado="Fechada" AND edit_data = (SELECT edit_data, id FROM reparacoes WHERE id_reparacao=re.id_reparacao ORDER BY edit_data DESC LIMIT 1)))
```

While querying with phpmyadmin, it gives me this error:

```
#1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
edit_data = (SELECT edit_data, id FROM reparacoes WHERE id_reparacao=re.id_reparacao ORDER BY edit_data DESC LIMIT 1)
```

you can not compare scalar field with something that have more than one column (i.e. is non-scalar, but row).

I guess correct is:

```
edit_data = (SELECT edit_data FROM reparacoes WHERE id_reparacao=re.id_reparacao ORDER BY edit_data DESC LIMIT 1)
```